# Speedup query execution time for this linq query

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have this query that does the following :

- Pull childrens from the database
- Filter this childrens to get the ones that cannot be join to the availableItems query (that are not in the availableItems table)
- Filter the availablesItems and retrieve them into memory
- Perform a left join with the availablesItems and childrensWithoutItems then perform cartesian product with the left join result
- Perfrom inner join with availableItems and childrens

Is there any tips to speedup the execution time ?

```cs
var authorizeType = new List<TreeNodeType> {
        TreeNodeType.Equipment,
        TreeNodeType.StructuredArea
    };

        
var childrens = await (from n in _db.TreeNodes.Where(n => n.TreeNodeId == treeNodeParentId)
                        from path in _db.TreeNodes.Where(p => (EF.Functions.Like(p.Path, n.Path + "%")) && authorizeType.Contains(p.Type))
                        select new
                        {
                            path.Name,
                            path.FullName,
                            path.Type,
                            path.HorusId,
                        }).ToListAsync();

var childrensWithoutItems = childrens.Where(i => !_db.AvailableItems.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(i.HorusId));

var availableitems = await _db.AvailableItems
    .Where(x => x.HorusId == null || childrens.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(x.HorusId.Value))
    .ToListAsync();

//without items
var withoutItems =
        (from c in childrensWithoutItems
        from co in availableitems
        join tree in childrens on co.HorusId equals tree.HorusId into left
        from le in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join i in items on co.ItemIdentifier equals i.Identifier
        where le == null
        select new OrganizationItemDetail {
            OrganizationPath = c.FullName,
            OrganizationChildName = c.Name,
            OrganizationType = c.Type,
            Name = i.Name,
            Packaging = i.Packaging.ToString(),
            ShortName = i.ShortName,
            Type = i.Type.ToString(),
            UnitValue = i.UnitValue,
        });


//with items 
var withItems = (from co in availableitems
                                join tree in childrens on co.HorusId equals tree.HorusId
                                join i in items on co.ItemIdentifier equals i.Identifier
                                select new OrganizationItemDetail {
                                    OrganizationPath = tree.FullName,
                                    OrganizationChildName = tree.Name,
                                    OrganizationType = tree.Type,
                                    Name = i.Name,
                                    Packaging = i.Packaging.ToString(),
                                    ShortName = i.ShortName,
                                    Type = i.Type.ToString(),
                                    UnitValue = i.UnitValue,
                                });

var res = withoutItems.Concat(withItems);
```

Desired result :

- After pulling the childrens I try to inner join Childrens and AvailableItems tables.
- I also want to perform a cartesian product on the AvailablesItems that cannot be join to Childrens (Left join) with the childrens that are not in AvailalblesItems (Right join). Meaning a cartesian product on the result of a right join with the result of a left join
- I want to join the two query and return the result

**Initial tables**

Items list

| ItemIdentifier | Name |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | rules1 |
| DB | rules2 |
| FF | rules3 |
| EE | rules4 |
| BB | rules5 |

*Childrens tables*

| Id | HorusId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **34** | A |
| 2 | **35** | B |
| 3 | **36** | C |
| 4 | 37 | D |
| 5 | 38 | E |

*AvailablesItems tables*

| Id | HorusId | IdentifierItems |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **34** | ABC |
| 2 | **35** | DB |
| 4 | **36** | FF |
| 5 | 37 | EE |
| 6 | 38 | BB |

**Step 1 results: (inner join on childrens and availableItems)**

*inner join*

| Name | HorusId | IdentifierItems |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | **34** | ABC |
| B | **35** | DB |
| C | **36** | FF |

**Step 2 results: (left join with availablesItems and childrens + cartesian product on left join results)**

*left join*

| IdentifierItems |
| --- |
| EE |
| BB |

*cartesian product on left join result*

| Name | IdentifierItems |
| --- | --- |
| D | EE |
| E | EE |
| D | BB |
| E | BB |

**Step 3 results : (Inner join with Items List and Step 2 results)**

| Name | ItemsListName | IdentifierItems |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | rules4 | EE |
| E | rules5 | BB |
| D | rules4 | EE |
| E | rules5 | BB |

**Step 4 results : Same thing but with Step1 results**

Comment: Whats the current execution time. Record that to give yourself a base line to work from for a start.

Comment: Whats the database? SqlServer?

Comment: @PeterMarshall SQLServer

Comment: Did the query plans give you any hints?

Comment: Can you post Model types also?

Comment: _"I have this query that does the following"_ ... can you put into words what you are _intending_ to get as a result by doing what you are doing? It's one thing to look if you are "doing it right" but you need to question if you are "doing the right thing", too.

Comment: @Fildor Step1 -> After pulling the childrens I try to inner join Childrens and AvailableItems tables. Step 2 -> I also want to perform a cartesian product on the AvailablesItems that cannot be join to Childrens (Left join) with the childrens that are not in AvailalblesItems (Right join). Meaning a cartesian product on the result of a right join with the result of a left join

Comment: No no no. That's the gibberish that's already in the question. You have information about Wiggles and Woggles and now you want to query which of the Wiggles have an associated Woggle, that's considered "available" or no Woggle at all. - Something like that is what I ask for.

Comment: Take the generated SQL and run it in SSMS.  Is that still too slow?  Can you optimise the SQL to improve it, and then reimplement that in Linq.

Comment: ^^ Don't be offended by "gibberish"... You see, your description is like "I want to multiply Pi with the square of the radius" which we can see you are doing. Now if your actual _goal_ is to get the area of a circle, that'd be ok but if it turns out, you wanted the circumference, we cannot know that by your description. And then we would be improving the wrong thing to begin with. See what I mean?

Comment: @quiz, you have loaded WHOLE `_db.AvailableItems` N times because of `ToListAsync`. If you want to get help, post model classes used in this query.

Comment: I do not see classes. I have not asked for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was the following line that was looping trough all the AvailableItems tables (huge table)  :

```
var childrensWithoutItems = childrens.Where(i => !availableitems.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(i.HorusId));
```

I have changed the orders of the queries from :

```
var childrensWithoutItems = childrens.Where(i => !availableitems.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(i.HorusId));

var availableitems = await _db.AvailableItems.Where(x => x.HorusId == null || childrens.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(x.HorusId.Value)).ToListAsync();
```

To :

```
var availableitems = await _db.AvailableItems.Where(x => x.HorusId == null || childrens.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(x.HorusId.Value)).ToListAsync();

var childrensWithoutItems = childrens.Where(i => !availableitems.Select(d => d.HorusId).Contains(i.HorusId));
```

I dont'see any issue by using ToListAsync while using the where clause since I am reusing mulitples times theses data to build my models

Executing time : before -> 6000ms, after -> 150ms